# How to make 2 div elements centered horizontally and vertically in CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

I am trying to center 2 div elements vertically and horizontally and this should work well and it usually does, but not here..

HTML

```
<div class="contact">
                    <h3>WHAT ARE YOU WAITING FOR?</h3>
                    <div class="cta-btn">
                        <a href="../contact-us/contact.html"><h3>CONTACT US</h3></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```css
.contact {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    .cta-btn {
        width: 8em;
        padding: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more code to show the issue. Especially the relevant HTML part and the CSS for the element with the text "WHAT ARE YOU WAITING FOR?"

Comment: Do you want the elements to be in a row like in the image or stacked in a column? Please be more clear because in the actual state the issue isn't reproducable...

Comment: You should apply border-radius for link, not for div .cta-btn

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways to achieve what you're looking for.
One uses flexboxes. Here you need an initial container that consumes your full window and into this container you put another container that is positioned in the center and into that you can put your content (code is shortened to minimum):

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flexcontainer {}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="flexcontainer">
    <span class="left">Left Content</span>
    <span class="right">Right Content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[edit]: Obviously, the initial container (.box here) could also be a header or something not spanning the full windows height. In this case, you would not have to position it absolute and define the top, bottom, left and right positions but could work with width and height or use a dynamic size.[/edit]

The other method is based on the assumption that you know the height of your content container:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 101px) auto;
  /* calc(50 percent of window height minus half the size of the container including borders!) */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct this code, adding follow properties in css:

```
<div class="contact">
    <h3>WHAT ARE YOU WAITING FOR?</h3>
    <div class="cta-btn">
        <a href="../contact-us/contact.html"><h3>CONTACT US</h3></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.contact {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

    h3 {
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .cta-btn {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.contact{
display:flex;
align:center;
}
.cta-btn{
display:flex;
align:center;
}

<div class="contact">
                    <h3>WHAT ARE YOU WAITING FOR?</h3>
                    <div class="cta-btn">
                        <a href="../contact-us/contact.html"><h3>CONTACT US</h3></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add in an explanation of the code you have posted.